# Convert Facebook Account to User/Password Account

Tags: runescape

I created a RuneScape account using the Facebook-Login.

Now I would like to remove this dependency, to be able to log in using user/password, instead of having to use facebook.

I added an email address, but I still can't seem to login using email+password.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Does Runescape have a support forum? This question might be better asked there as it IS account related and is therefore Runescape's responsibility to deal with.

Comment: well, i would ask there, if i could post. for that i don't have enough skill points ingame.

Comment: I see. Sorry I didn't know you needed skill points to get support from them.

Comment: If I paid for playing, I would get support from the beginning ;)

Comment: What happens if you dissociate your Facebook account from your character? Wouldn't you then NEED to create an account name? Perhaps then it'll prompt you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runescape, as with (almost) every other website that allows you to use Facebook to login, does not have any kind of cross-compatibility capabilities, so in this case once you make an account associated with Facebook, you're stuck with it. Sorry.

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I am going to post an answer in the offchance that you check this thread again.

If you go to the official Runescape website at www.runescape.com you will see that there is a login button in the top right corner. If you sign in to the website using your facebook created account, the website will prompt you to upgrade to a full account by providing a new email (your username) and a password for the account.

Answer (score -1):

This question does have a way to solve this now. You can convert your facebook account into a full runescape account by following the wiki guide here:

[Runescape Wiki](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/How_to_turn_a_Facebook_account_into_a_full_account)

It isn't entirely accurate on the steps they say to follow, so some improvising is needed.